# Ubuntu 18.0: lowercase "y" key not working OR repeating input

Tags: keyboard, layout

for some reason, I am not sure why, my lowercase "y" key is not working properly anymore.

In terminal it repeats the last word of a command. I did try with german and us keyboard layout.
If I try SHIFT+y it is useable as uppercase letter "Y" (at least).

In KDE search itself the lowercasse "y" can't be used (not showing up) as well.
In console (ctrl+shift+f1) it shows "^Z" instead of the lowercase "y".

So far I had no luck to find the source of this problem.
Hope someone here might have an idea how to solve it.

Comment: It seems you might have created a shortcut with the letter y or changed the keymap somehow.

Comment: I noticed pressing the "y" key longer will write the letter, but I can't seem to find where this (setting/ shortcut ?) might come from, to fix it :/

Comment: found out holding down AltGr + y leads to writing the letter "y" - anyone knows where top find and fix this?